# Detect that OS X app was launched as login item?

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication

My app is sometimes set to launch at login.

If it is automatically started because of a login I do not want to show it's window.

The app has a status bar item that will run when the user logs in, but the user doesn't want to have the window pop up every time I log in.

How can I tell during my application's startup that this was an automatic start so the window can be made invisible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is launched there are a couple of inputs: command line arguments and the environment variables. I took a look at launching the Alfred.app from the dock and via login. There was nothing in the arguments or environment that would indicate the source of the launch.

There are a couple of ways an application could be started on login. Either via the "Login Items" in the user's System Preferences or via a LaunchAgent in one of the Library/LaunchAgents. From what I can tell the "Login Items" is the most user friendly way to add something to launch at startup (and disable it in the future) but it looks like the equivalent to launching it from the dock or application directory. As a result we don't have enough information to determine the source of the launch via this method.

Using [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) we can specify an XML file in the user's ~/Library/LaunchAgents directory that will start a program with a specific set of command line arguments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>info.evanlong.apps.sandbox</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>/path/to/your/app</string>
          <string>--this-started-via-login</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There are many configuration options for launched including the ability to set the environment variables for a process. All that can be found on the [launchd.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) man page.

For the problem you are trying to solve I can see a couple solutions:

1. launchd (little bit more work to maintain and support)
2. Continue to use "Login Items" with some cleverness.

I think option 2 is the best approach and more in line with how other apps work. The cleverness is that when the application is first launched you don't show the main window. Only display the icon in the status bar. If the application is launched the running app should get an applicationWillBecomeActive/applicationDidBecomeActive on the app delegate. When this happens after the first launch you'll want to display your applications window. Keep in mind that will/did become active callbacks will also be called on the applications first launch. So you'll want to check for that with something like this:

```
static BOOL IS_FIRST_CALL = YES;

@implementation LWAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
}

- (void)applicationWillBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (IS_FIRST_CALL) {
        NSLog(@"first call");
        IS_FIRST_CALL = NO;
    }
    else {
        // Display the application window
        NSLog(@"subsequent calls");
    }
}
@end
```